# How to create a command line pipe? (xcode mac os x)

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal

> How to create a command line pipe? (xcode mac os x) Hello I want to
>   create a command line with xcode (mac os x) that had the quality of
>   being used in pipe after "|" .
>
> i know that by using xargs we can pass arguments stored in stdin into
>   arguments.
>
> I would like to understand how to create a pipable command line. Thank
>   you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, if we define the hand function that should receive the
>   arguments to execute. In a rudimentary way we will write (in C):

```
         int main (int argc, char ** argv) 
    {
     char buf [512] = ""; 
    char buf1[512] = "";
int f;
```

> and achieve some things
>
> the first argument of the argument array, contains in any case the no
>   of the command line that you are creating ex: argv [0] "echo" and the
>   argument following the one you wish to use, 'here for echo argv [1]
>   "the sun shines" of course if echo is able to receive an argument
>   after "|" (pipe) for example: echo "the sun is shining" | echo, but
>   echo do not use the pipe.
>
> For our main function, is elementarily we will check if argv [1]
>   contains an argument by

```
     if (argv [1] == NULL)
>     {
```

> ```
>   there we arbitrarily take the guess that argv [1] is empty. as a reminder our command line is located after a pipe "|" if our argv [1]
> ```
>
> is empty, it will need to find an argument to continue using our
>   command line, for this we accept the postulate that if the command
>   line is placed after "|" pipe is that the output of the previous
>   command is not empty from where what will follow

```
>  f = open ("/ dev / stdin", O_RDONLY);
>  read (f, buf, sizeof (buf)); 
  memcpy (buf1, buf, sizeof (buf));
```

> now we have opened the stream "stdin" which necessarily contains the
>   output of the previous command, we use 2 buffers buf [512] and buf1
>   [512], because we can not fill argv [1], now that we have our
>   arguments in a buffer, one can realize the continuation of the
>   execution of the command, as if it were about argv [1].

Answer (score 0):

> In objective-c or in C simply, to give an line command the virtue to
>   be used ien pipeline as a result of the use of "|" after another
>   command line, it is necessary to redirect "stdin" towards the entry of
>   the command line as it was an argument ("argv"). From there by
>   mastering a little programming in "C", one must arrive at its ends to
>   make a command line create with xcode, usable after "|" .